# Unicode problems with Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a few files that I am trying to load onto jupyter notebooks.
One is json file which contains a list of words and it was saved with utf8 encoding. It loaded perfectly using

```
encoding = "utf-8-sig"
```

later I am trying to load a csv which contains a huge dataframe. I saved the csv using UTF-8 encoding, but then I try to load it with

```
encoding = "utf-8"
```

I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position
>   12: invalid continuation byte

I loads without any errors when I use `latin1` encoding. But then when I try to printout my dataframe, I get lot's of bad unicode characters. If I load the same file to, let's say, Spyder editor, I get all the right characters. Is there any fix for this issue?